# Running an app on Azure and protecting signups

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I'm about to finish an app that will run on Windows Phone and Android.  It uses an azure web API and push notification service.

I was wondering if there is any standard or recommended way of protecting the 'signup' or 'register' functionality within an app like this?  I note that some popular apps like snapchat will send you a text to verify the registration process.  That would be ideal but obviously seems unfeasible for a modest app such as mine :-)

Can anyone enlighten me to some common ways to protect the 'register' functionality of a mobile app?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use Azure authentication (like in Azure Mobile Services) and all that's handled by Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure provides feature sets like Azure Mobile Services that provide authentication features that you can use in your Windows Phone apps.  I doubt the authentication Azure Mobile Services uses is restricted to just Azure Mobile Services, but more information on getting started with this authentication can be found here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/resources-wp8/#header-2